# Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server

In my local server I'm using SQL Server 2008 and in production we have SQL Server 2005. Only in production server I'm getting an error:

> Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string this error

while executing the trigger.

This is my code:

```
SET @nextSemesterValue = (select min(semesterYear * 100 + Month(semesterType + ' 1 2000')) as yearmonth
                          from table 
                          where (semesterYear * 100 + Month(semesterType + ' 1 2000')) > YEAR(getdate()) * 100 + MONTH(getdate())
                            and courseId = @courseId)
```

here `semsterYear` is an `Integer` column, and `semesterType` is string.

Is there any problem in above code? Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes. there is a problem. otherwise you wouldn't get an error. However we need more details - what kind of values do you you have in `semesterType`? To point you to the right direction -  are there values where the conversion is successful? if there are, what's the difference between those values and the values where the conversion is not successful?

Comment: semesterType may contains January,May,September

Comment: This is a trigger i dont know exactly where it is failing but i guess the above code is creating some problem

Comment: Well then, I'm guessing you have a typo somewhere in the `semester type` that prevents sql server to recognize the month. My suggestion is to use a lookup table for months (1: January, 2: February etc`) and keep the int value in the main table instead of the month name). This will prevent the need to convert the month name to a date and also prevent the possibility of a typo when entering data to the table.

Comment: what is your sem year and sem type value.

Comment: check my below answer , let me know if helpfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple replace your getting month code with below code

```
DATEPART(MONTH,semesterType + ' 1 2000')
```

Comment: Read the comments of the question - semester type holds the month name, not the month number.

Comment: This will result with the same errors for the same reasons.

Comment: make sure that semesterType  is correct month name e.g(june,july,august) etc and also verify it not return null value

Comment: if every thing is going fine then may sql server 2005 are very old version , and not supporting such type of sql functions

Comment: [read this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17956/is-there-any-significant-difference-between-monthdate-and-datepartmonth-date)